# Delete child items recursively in Sitecore CMS.NET

Tags: c#, recursion, sitecore

I have the following structure in my Sitecore media library

> images/department/sub-department/product/

And I want to delete all of the images in code a department at a time. At the moment I have

```
Item[] items = database.SelectItems("/sitecore/media library/images/department1//*");            

Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine engine = new Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine(database);

using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
    foreach (Item item in items)
    {
        engine.DeleteItem(item))
    }
}
```

The problem is it only deletes the child images of department1 and nothing underneath that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DataEngine is a very low level API, which shouldn't be used without a reason.

Deleting all subitems simultaneously is easy:

Item department1 = database.GetItem("/sitecore/media library/images/department1");
department1.DeleteChildren();

This will leave department1 item, but everything under it will be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what kind of reason would you use the DataEngine for?

Comment: Quick answer is never, unless you know what you're doing.

Longer answer is that sometimes people need a hardcore customization or a workaround, that cannot be achieved using higher level, public APIs. But even then, it's likely to be done by Sitecore support stuff, this is not something we document

Comment: May I also suggest using Sitecore Rocks extension for Visual Studio. You can view your content tree right from in VS and perform a "commandy" by right clicking anywhere in the content tree and selecting a query analyzer. One used for this case would be:

delete from /sitecore/media library/images/department1/*

You are also allowed to use Item attributes, such as [@@templateid=""], etc. Best of luck.